# JSON transformation for PHP

Tags: php, json

Is there any reliable standardized way to transform JSON on the server side? (JSONT perhaps)

Can't really think of a way to use XSLT for that, or is there?

Edit: I should've been more specific. A somewhat standardized transformation is what I'm looking for: using json_decode and json_encode doesn't do that, it converts between formats. Converting one JSON string into another is what I'm curious about.

Comment: If you haven't got any answer, please elaborate your issue because your question seems to be too generic.

Comment: Spcifically, I'm looking for implementations of http://goessner.net/articles/jsont/ for PHP; any other documented transformation technology suitable for working with JSON will also do.

Comment: To me, this question seems very specific; just that the ones answering don't seem to be aware of what XSLT is and what you meant by transformation. I am also looking for a way to transform JSON, the only place I've seen it is with NoSQL databases that select information in a transformed format from data stored as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, no php-based solutions are known to the community.

Answer (score 4):

PHP offers `json_encode()`, see [the php manual on json_decode()](http://at.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php).
If you're receiving JSON values you can decode them with `json_decode()`.
Those function require the JSON-extension installed (which is a default).

JSONT is a client side library to transform JSON data into HTML, to use it your client webpage has to implement http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsont/jsont.js.
You just need to feed it with an json object containing the information.

For example if you want to add an link to this question:

```
<div id="jsont-space">
<?php
$jsontLink = new stdClass();
$jsontLink->uri = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656055/json-transformation-for-php';
$jsontLink->title = 'Question on Stackoverflow about: JSON transformation for PHP';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var transforms = { "self": "<a href=\"{uri}\" title='{title}'>{$.title}</a>" };
var data = <?php echo json_encode($jsontLink); ?>;
document.write(jsonT(data, transforms));
</script>
</div>
```

This is of course something very quick&dirty. But it should explain the whole variant of

- defining the data
- defining transformations
- applying those to a page

here are [some additional examples on JSONT](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsont/jsont-test.html) (look @ source)

**Edit:**
Added information about JSONT & implementation example

Comment: all those out there who love to downvote, if you'd leave a comment why i could improve my answer. thx.

Comment: My question was specifically about JSONT (or a replacement technology) on the server, my apologies if that is not stated clear enough. I am well aware of the client-side solutions where javascript support is quite natural.

Comment: i'm sorry, my misconception. I could only find a ruby implementation additionally to the JS one.

Answer (score 2):

```
$my_array=array("first", "second", "third"); 

json_encode($my_array); //["first","second","third"]
```

As of php version 5.3 you can:

```
json_encode($my_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // {"0":"first", "1":"second","2":"third"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what you want to transform it into. But as Samuel says, your best bet to get you on the right road is indeed `json_encode()` or `json_decode()` as this will allow you to transform an array or object into JSON string, or from a string into an object (using decode)

Comment: _Transformation_ as in converting one JSON construct into another.

Answer (score 0):

Original jsonT client side

```
    /*  This work is licensed under Creative Commons GNU LGPL License.

    License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/
   Version: 0.9
    Author:  Stefan Goessner/2006
    Web:     http://goessner.net/ 
*/

function jsonT(self, rules) {
   var T = {
      output: false,
      init: function() {
         for (var rule in rules)
            if (rule.substr(0,4) != "self")
               rules["self."+rule] = rules[rule];
         return this;
      },
      apply: function(expr) {
         var trf = function(s){ return s.replace(/{([A-Za-z0-9_\$\.\[\]\'@\(\)]+)}/g, 
                                  function($0,$1){return T.processArg($1, expr);})},
             x = expr.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/g, "[*]"), res;
         if (x in rules) {
            if (typeof(rules[x]) == "string")
               res = trf(rules[x]);
            else if (typeof(rules[x]) == "function")
               res = trf(rules[x](eval(expr)).toString());
         }
         else 
            res = T.eval(expr);
         return res;
      },
      processArg: function(arg, parentExpr) {
         var expand = function(a,e){return (e=a.replace(/^\$/,e)).substr(0,4)!="self" ? ("self."+e) : e; },
             res = "";
         T.output = true;
         if (arg.charAt(0) == "@")
            res = eval(arg.replace(/@([A-za-z0-9_]+)\(([A-Za-z0-9_\$\.\[\]\']+)\)/, 
                                   function($0,$1,$2){return "rules['self."+$1+"']("+expand($2,parentExpr)+")";}));
         else if (arg != "$")
            res = T.apply(expand(arg, parentExpr));
         else
            res = T.eval(parentExpr);
         T.output = false;
         return res;
      },
      eval: function(expr) {
         var v = eval(expr), res = "";
         if (typeof(v) != "undefined") {
            if (v instanceof Array) {
               for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++)
                  if (typeof(v[i]) != "undefined")
                     res += T.apply(expr+"["+i+"]");
            }
            else if (typeof(v) == "object") {
               for (var m in v)
                  if (typeof(v[m]) != "undefined")
                     res += T.apply(expr+"."+m);
            }
            else if (T.output)
               res += v;
         }
         return res;
      }
   };
   return T.init().apply("self");
}

/*
////////////////////////////////
// SAMPLE SECTION
////////////////////////////////

<html>
<head>
<title> JSONT - Tests </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsont.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var o = [], t = [];

t[1] = { "self": "<table>{pnt}</table>",
         "pnt": "<tr><td>{pnt.x}</td><td>{pnt.y}</td></tr>" };
o[1] = { pnt: { x:2, y:3 }};

t[2] = { "self": "<table><tr>{$}</tr></table>",
         "self[*]": "<td>{$}</td>" };
o[2] = [ 1, 2 ];

t[3] = { "self": "<table>\n{$}\n</table>",
          "self[*]": "<tr>{$}</tr>\n",
          "self[*][*]": "<td>{$}</td>" };
o[3] = [[1,2],[3,4]];

t[4] = { "self": "<div>\n{p}\n</div>",
          "p": "<table><tr>{$}</tr></table>\n",
          "p[*]": "<td>{$.x}</td><td>{$.y}</td>" };
o[4] = {a:"hello", p:[{x:1,y:2},{x:3,y:4}]};

t[5] = { "self": "<a href=\"{uri}\" title='{title}'>{$.title}</a>" };
o[5] = { uri:"http://somewhere.org", title:"somewhere homepage" };

t[6] = { "menu": "<menu>\n  <header>{menu.header}</header>\n{menu.items}</menu>",
         "menu.items[*]": function(x){
                            return x ? "  <item action=\""+x.id+" id=\""+x.id+"\">"+(x.label||x.id)+"</li>\n" 
                                     : "  <separator/>\n";} };
o[6] = {"menu": {
          "header": "SVG Viewer",
          "items": [
            {"id": "Open"},
            {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
            null,
            {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
            {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
            {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
            null,
            {"id": "Quality"},
            {"id": "Pause"},
            {"id": "Mute"},
            null,
            {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
            {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
            {"id": "Copy"},
            {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
            {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
            {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
            null,
            {"id": "Help"},
            {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]}};

t[7] = { "self": "<p> {a} {b} {c} {d} </p>" };
o[7] = { a:false, b:null, d:true };

t[8] = { "self": "<p> {a} </p>",
         "a": function(x) {return x ? 'black' : 'white';} };
o[8] = { "a": true };

t[9] = { "A": "<div>{A.a1} and {A.a2}</div>" };
o[9] = { "A" : { "a1": "a1val", "a2": "a2val" },
         "B" : { "b1": "b1val", "b2": "b2val" } };

o[10] = { "line": { "p1": {"x":2, "y":3},
                    "p2": {"x":4, "y":5} }};
t[10] = { "self": "<svg>{line}</svg>",
             "line": "<line x1=\"{$.p1.x}\" y1=\"{$.p1.y}\"" +
                           "x2=\"{$.p2.x}\" y2=\"{$.p2.y}\" />" };

o[11] = ["red", "green", "blue"];
t[11] = {"self": "<ul>\n{$}</ul>\n",
            "self[*]": "  <li>{$}</li>\n"};
o[12] = { "color": "blue",
          "closed": true,
          "points": [[10,10],[20,10],[20,20],[10,20]] };
t[12] = { "self": "<svg><{closed} stroke=\"{color}\" points=\"{points}\" /></svg>",
          "closed": function(x){return x ? "polygon" : "polyline";}, 
          "points[*][*]": "{$} " };

o[13] = {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File:",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}};

t[13] = { "menu": "<menu id=\"{$.id}\" value=\"{$.value}\">\n"+
                  "  <popup>\n{$.popup.menuitem}  </popup>\n</menu>",
          "menu.popup.menuitem[*]": "    <menuitem value=\"{$.value}\""+
                                    "onclick=\"{$.onclick}\" />\n" };

o[14] = [{"u":"http://www.ericclapton.com/hello",
            "d":"Eric Clapton",
            "t":["guitarist","blues","rock"]},
           {"u":"http://www.bbking.com/",
            "d":"B.B. King : Official Site",
            "t":["guitarist","blues"]},
           {"u":"http://www.stevieraysbluesbar.com/",
            "d":"Louisville's House of Blues",
            "t":["guitarist","blues","rock"]}];

t[14] = { "self": "<ul>\n{$}</ul>",
          "self[*]": " <li>\n"+
                     "  <img style='position:absolute;display:none;'"+
                     "    width='16' height='16'\n"+
                     "    onload='showImage(this)' src='{@icon($.u)}'/>\n"+
                     "  <a style='margin-left:20px;' href='{$.u}'>{$.d}</a>\n"+
                     " </li>\n",
          "icon": function(x){return x.split('/').splice(0,3).join('/')+'/favicon.ico';}           
           };

t[15] = { "self": "<p> {$.a} </p>",
          "a": function(x){return x ? 'black' : 'white'} }
o[15] = { "a": true };

t[16] = { "self": "<p> {a}, {b}, {b.x} </p>",
          "b": "hello",
          "b.x": "" };
o[16] = { "a": false, "b": null };

t[17] = { "self": function(x){ return x.length; } }
o[17] = [ 1, 2, 1 ];

function test()
{
    var N1 = 1; // 1
    var N2 = 17; // 17

    for(i=N1; i<N2+1; i++ )
    {
        show(jsonT(o[i], t[i]));
    }
}

function show(s) { document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += (s+"\n").replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") + "<hr/>"; }
window.onload = test;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<pre id="out"></pre>
</body>
</html> 

*/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php

/*  This work is licensed under Creative Commons GNU LGPL License.

    License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/
   Version: 0.9
    Author:  Stefan Goessner/2006
    Web:     http://goessner.net/ 

    TRANSLATED TO PHP BY ANONYMOUS, 19:45 05.12.2015
*/

class jsont_class
{
    //SET TO true FOR GET ERROR MESSAGES
    var $debug = false;

    private $output = false;

    private $pa_h1e = "";
    private $pa_h2e = "";

    private $rules = null;
    private $self = null;

    private function ecran_js2php($s)
    {
        if(is_string($s))
        {
            $s = str_replace("[", ".", $s);
            $s = str_replace("]", ".", $s);
            $s = str_replace("..", ".", $s);
            $s = trim($s, ".");
        }
        return $s;
    }

    private function init(&$rules, &$self)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////
        // IN PHP Object and Array FROM Javascript THE SAME
        // MAKING x[i] AS x.i
        //////////////////////////////////
        $r = array();
        $s = array();

        foreach ($rules as $key => $value)
        {
            $nk = $this->ecran_js2php($key);
            $r[$nk] = $value;
        }
        foreach ($self as $key => $value)
        {
            $nk = $this->ecran_js2php($key);
            $s[$nk] = $value;
        }

        $rules = $r;
        $self = $s;
        //////////////////////////////////

        foreach ($rules as $rule => $___)
        {
            if (substr($rule, 0, 4) != "self")
            {
                $rules['self.' . $rule] = $rules[$rule];
            }
        }
    }

    private function check_is_func($str_f) { return (substr($str_f, 0, 8) == "function"); }

    private function run_func($str_f, $expr)
    {
        if ($this->check_is_func($str_f))
        {
            //return " FBODY: [" . $str_f . "] ARGS: [" . ($expr != null) ? $expr:$obj . "] ";

            //ORIGINAL: $param = eval($expr);
            $param = null;
            $this->expand_chain($expr, $param);

            $body = strstr($str_f, "{");

            $func = create_function('', $body);
            return $func($param);
        }

        return $this->debug ? ("ERR: run_func(). NOT FUNCTION: FBODY: [" . $str_f . "] ARGS: [" . $expr . "] "):"";
    }

    private function expand($a, $e)
    {
        return (substr($e = preg_replace('/^\$/', $e, $a, 1), 0, 4) != "self") ? 'self.' . $e : $e;
    }

    private function pa_h1($p)
    {
        return $this->processArg($p[1], $this->pa_h1e);
    }
    private function pa_h2($p)
    {
        //IN ORIGINAL HERE CALCULATING (!)STRING FUNC/FUNC_ARG WICH RUN AFTER THAT BY eval
        //ORIGINAL: return $this->rules['self.' . $p[1] . '](' . $this->expand($p[2], $this->pa_h2e . ')' );

        //BUT IN PHP VERSION WE RUN FUNCTION HERE
        return $this->run_func($this->rules['self.' . $p[1]], $this->expand($p[2], $this->pa_h2e) );
    }
    private function trf($expr, $s)
    {
        $this->pa_h1e = $expr;
        return preg_replace_callback('/{([A-Za-z0-9_\$\.\[\]\'@\(\)]+)}/', array($this, 'pa_h1'), $s);
    }

    private function apply($expr)
    {
        //ORIGINAL: $x = preg_replace('/\[[0-9]+\]/', "[*]", $expr);
        $x = preg_replace('/.[0-9]+/', ".*", $expr);

        $res = null;
        if (isset($this->rules[$x]))
        {
            $rx = $this->rules[$x];

            if(gettype($rx) == "string")
            {
                if ($this->check_is_func($rx))
                {
                    //ORIGINAL: $res = $this->trf($expr, (string)$rx(eval(expr))));
                    $res = $this->trf($expr, (string)$this->run_func($rx, $expr));
                }
                else { $res = $this->trf($expr, $rx); }
            }
        }
        else { $res = $this->jst_eval($expr); }

        return $res;
    }

    private function processArg($arg, $parentExpr)
    {
        $res = "";
        $this->output = true;
        if ($arg[0] == "@")
        {
            $this->pa_h2e = $parentExpr;

            //ORIGINAL: $res = eval(preg_replace_callback('/@([A-za-z0-9_]+)\(([A-Za-z0-9_\$\.\[\]\']+)\)/', array($this, 'pa_h2'), $arg, 1));

            $res = preg_replace_callback('/@([A-za-z0-9_]+)\(([A-Za-z0-9_\$\.\[\]\']+)\)/', array($this, 'pa_h2'), $arg, 1);
        }
        else if ($arg != "$")
        {
            $res = $this->apply($this->expand($arg, $parentExpr));
        }
        else
        {
            $res = $this->jst_eval($parentExpr);
        }

        $this->output = false;
        return $res;
    }

    private function expand_chain($chain_, &$ret_val)
    {
        $ok = false;
        $ret_val = null;

        //$chain_ = str_replace(" ", "", $chain_);
        $chain = explode(".", $chain_);

        if($sc = sizeof($chain))
        {
            $rt = null;
            for($i = 0; $i<$sc; $i++)
            {
                $key = $chain[$i];

                if($key == "self") { $rt = $this->self; $ok = true; continue; }

                if(!array_key_exists($key, $rt)) { $rt = null; $ok = false; break; }

                $rt = $rt[$key];
            }

            $ret_val = $rt;
        }

        if($this->debug && !$ok) { print("ERROR: expand_chain() CAN'T EXPAND THE PARAM: [" . $chain_ . "] CHECK YOU JSONT SCRIPT SYNTAX" ); };

        return $ok;
    }

    private function jst_eval($expr)
    {
        $res = "";
        if($this->expand_chain($expr, $v))
        {
            if(is_array($v))
            {
                foreach($v as $key => $value)
                {
                    $res .= $this->apply($expr . '.' . $key  );
                }
            }
            else  { if ($this->output) { $res .= $v; } }
        }

        return $res;
    }

    function jsonT($self_, $rules_)
    {
        $this->rules = $rules_;
        $this->self = $self_;

        $this->init($this->rules, $this->self);

        return $this->apply("self");
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////
// SAMPLE HERE
//////////////////////////////////////////
function j2o($j2o_, &$arr, &$json_str)
{
    if($j2o_) $arr = json_decode($json_str, TRUE);
    else $json_str = json_encode($arr);
}


function show($s)
{
    return preg_replace('/\n/', "<br/>", preg_replace('/>/', "&gt;", preg_replace('/</', "&lt;", preg_replace('/&/', "&amp;", $s . "\n")))) . "<hr/>";
}


main();

function main()
{
$t = array();
$o = array();

$t[1] = '{ "self": "<table>{pnt}</table>",
         "pnt": "<tr><td>{pnt.x}</td><td>{pnt.y}</td></tr>" }';
$o[1] = '{ "pnt": { "x":2, "y":3 }}';

$t[2] = '{ "self": "<table><tr>{$}</tr></table>",
         "self[*]": "<td>{$}</td>" }';
$o[2] = '[ 1, 2 ]';

$t[3] = '{ "self": "<table>\n{$}\n</table>",
          "self[*]": "<tr>{$}</tr>\n",
          "self[*][*]": "<td>{$}</td>" }';
$o[3] = '[[1,2],[3,4]]';

$t[4] = '{ "self": "<div>\n{p}\n</div>",
          "p": "<table><tr>{$}</tr></table>\n",
          "p[*]": "<td>{$.x}</td><td>{$.y}</td>" }';
$o[4] = '{"a":"hello", "p":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":4}]}';

$t[5] = '{ "self": "<a href=\"{uri}\" title=\"{title}\">{$.title}</a>" }';
$o[5] = '{ "uri":"http://somewhere.org", "title":"somewhere homepage" }';

$t[6] = '{ "menu": "<menu>\n  <header>{menu.header}</header>\n{menu.items}</menu>",
         "menu.items[*]": "function(){$x = func_get_args(); return $x[0] ? \"  <item action=\" . $x[0][\"id\"] . \" id=\" . $x[0][\"id\"] . \">\" . (array_key_exists(\"label\", $x[0]) ? $x[0][\"label\"]:$x[0][\"id\"]) . \"</li>\n\" : \"  <separator/>\n\";}" }';
$o[6] = '{"menu": {
          "header": "SVG Viewer",
          "items": [
            {"id": "Open"},
            {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
            null,
            {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
            {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
            {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
            null,
            {"id": "Quality"},
            {"id": "Pause"},
            {"id": "Mute"},
            null,
            {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
            {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
            {"id": "Copy"},
            {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
            {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
            {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
            {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
            null,
            {"id": "Help"},
            {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]}}';

$t[7] = '{ "self": "<p> {a} {b} {c} {d} </p>" }';
$o[7] = '{ "a":false, "b":null, "d":true }';

$t[8] = '{ "self": "<p> {a} </p>",
         "a": "function() {$x = func_get_args(); return $x[0] ? \"black\" : \"white\";}" }';
$o[8] = '{ "a": true }';

$t[9] = '{ "A": "<div>{A.a1} and {A.a2}</div>" }';
$o[9] = '{ "A" : { "a1": "a1val", "a2": "a2val" },
         "B" : { "b1": "b1val", "b2": "b2val" } }';

$o[10] = '{ "line": { "p1": {"x":2, "y":3},
                    "p2": {"x":4, "y":5} }}';
$t[10] = '{ "self": "<svg>{line}</svg>",
             "line": "<line x1=\"{$.p1.x}\" y1=\"{$.p1.y}\" x2=\"{$.p2.x}\" y2=\"{$.p2.y}\" />" }';

$o[11] = '["red", "green", "blue"]';
$t[11] = '{"self": "<ul>\n{$}</ul>\n",
            "self[*]": "  <li>{$}</li>\n"}';
$o[12] = '{ "color": "blue",
          "closed": true,
          "points": [[10,10],[20,10],[20,20],[10,20]] }';
$t[12] = '{ "self": "<svg><{closed} stroke=\"{color}\" points=\"{points}\" /></svg>",
          "closed": "function(){$x = func_get_args(); return $x[0] ? \"polygon\" : \"polyline\";}", 
          "points[*][*]": "{$} " }';

$o[13] = '{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File:",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}';

$t[13] = '{ "menu": "<menu id=\"{$.id}\" value=\"{$.value}\">\n <popup>\n{$.popup.menuitem}  </popup>\n</menu>",
          "menu.popup.menuitem[*]": "    <menuitem value=\"{$.value}\" onclick=\"{$.onclick}\" />\n" }';

$o[14] = '[{"u":"http://www.ericclapton.com/hello",
            "d":"Eric Clapton",
            "t":["guitarist","blues","rock"]},
           {"u":"http://www.bbking.com/",
            "d":"B.B. King : Official Site",
            "t":["guitarist","blues"]},
           {"u":"http://www.stevieraysbluesbar.com/",
            "d":"Louisville\'s House of Blues",
            "t":["guitarist","blues","rock"]}]';

$t[14] = '{ "self": "<ul>\n{$}</ul>",
          "self[*]": " <li>\n <img style=\"position:absolute;display:none;\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"\n  onload=\"showImage(this)\" src=\"{@icon($.u)}\"/>\n   <a style=\"margin-left:20px;\" href=\"{$.u}\">{$.d}</a>\n </li>\n",
          "icon": "function(){$x = func_get_args(); $pieces = explode(\"/\", $x[0]); return join(\"/\", array_splice($pieces, 0, 3)) . \"/favicon.ico\";}"}';

$t[15] = '{ "self": "<p> {$.a} </p>",
          "a": "function(){$x = func_get_args(); return $x[0] ? \"black\" : \"white\"; }" }';
$o[15] = '{ "a": true }';

$t[16] = '{ "self": "<p> {a}, {b}, {b.x} </p>",
          "b": "hello",
          "b.x": "" }';
$o[16] = '{ "a": false, "b": null }';

$t[17] = '{ "self": "function(){ $x = func_get_args(); return count($x[0]); }" }';
$o[17] = '[ 1, 2, 1 ]';

    $jstc = new jsont_class();

    $jst = array();
    $jso = array();

    $N1 = 1; // 1
    $N2 = 17; // 17

    for($i=$N1; $i<$N2+1; $i++ )
    {
        j2o(true, $jso[$i], $o[$i]);
        j2o(true, $jst[$i], $t[$i]);

        print(show($jstc->jsonT($jso[$i], $jst[$i])));
    }
} 

?>
```